# Any option for moving the banner images in frontend for admin

Tags: wordpress

I need to give option for moving the uploaded image in banner, as we are having in our Facebook cover photo. Is it possible for doing the same process in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can put link and check admin is logged in or not.if admin is login than display link of edit and change banner using code other wise display popup and give admin rights for changing image.

Comment: i cant get what u r saying. kindly explain it clearly